# why docker daemon already startup but still not able to list the docker running task

Tags: docker

I am start docker(19.03.1) using this command in CentOS 7.4:

```
[root@ops001 ~]# dockerd
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.495452068+08:00] Starting up
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.496948674+08:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.496992096+08:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.497023029+08:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] }  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.497038420+08:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.497209216+08:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00071db20, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.497753603+08:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00071db20, READY  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.498779029+08:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.498797692+08:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.498815974+08:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] }  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.498826873+08:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.498878131+08:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000139b40, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.499129163+08:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000139b40, READY  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.533436628+08:00] Loading containers: start.
ERRO[2020-04-12T22:35:39.540803539+08:00] Failed to load container mount d794ba7c8b44c278e832ca8acb03d9feaf27b86c3760fd3ee8b2ea9ceebb04b7: mount does not exist
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:40.217719280+08:00] Removing stale sandbox 0a43d02f8e048bd40681184ea250eea2544097479f309a22428accb45323c2fe (e4dbf0fc8fe729d18d13610a927d2bccff29a0a3a61fe1fcca24b15f3e9106be)
WARN[2020-04-12T22:35:40.252193267+08:00] Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint de761b3ebcb8035eaf1e0ddae667c31d09794f7ddb1df6b44b495cd17f5a59b1 4d464ba20130c163e7084407f25b5cff86fa478596834683c3c28ea1c84badae], retrying....
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:40.298580208+08:00] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.30.224.0/21. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:40.806008604+08:00] Loading containers: done.
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:40.836875725+08:00] Docker daemon                                 commit=74b1e89 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=19.03.1
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:40.836965995+08:00] Daemon has completed initialization
INFO[2020-04-12T22:35:40.848651741+08:00] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock
```

but when I run list docker it shows error like this:

```
[root@ops001 ~]# docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
[root@ops001 ~]# docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.1
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.5
 Git commit:        74b1e89
 Built:             Thu Jul 25 21:21:07 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

why the docker already startup but could not list by docker command? where is going wrong? what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Does `sudo docker ps` gives you the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start docker daemon use: `sudo service docker start`.

If you want docker daemon to start on system boot: `sudo systemctl enable docker`